Special Character is escaped in Subject in SendGrid V3 Java API
I am using Sendgrid Java V3 API for sending emails. If the subject contains any special character such as &, Sendgrid doesn't decode it properly. & is converting to: &amp;
Personalization personalization = new Personalization();
personalization.addTo("to Email address");
personalization.addDynamicTemplateData("subject", "Abc & Xyz");
Mail mail = new Mail();
mail.addPersonalization(personalization);
mail.setFrom("from email address");

Request request = new Request();
request.setMethod(Method.POST);
request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
request.setBody(mail.build());
sendGrid.api(request);

The subject should display special character properly as '&'
Expected subject in email: Abc & Xyz
Actual subject in mail: Abc &amp; Xyz

I have managed to resolved it. Have to update the Template settings in Sendgrid for the template being used. Used {{{subject}}} for the Subject field.
